# Javascript Array, Object, Date not defined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Strangest situation ever, but I've reproduced it on three PCs already. Only happens in internet explorer 9 (not 8, just 9).

It happens at the site of my friend, this is not a plug, but here is the url: [IE bug with javascript](http://www.kennisateliers.be/nl/programma_%28custom%29/2012/kennisateliers_gaat_weer_vreemd-32.html)

The magic error happens when you click one of the links, for example "Nog fiscaal interessant ..."

This opens a popup, with inside an iframe that hosts a movie player. The movie frame complains, in IE9, about "Object not defined", "Array not defined", "Date" not defined.

What could be going on?

Comment: Well perhaps something isn't defined. Have you used the IE9 developer tools to investigate at all? The `<body>` tag is set up to call "initialize" in its "load" handler. Where is that function *supposed* to be?

Comment: Yes, the tool breakpoints at the error "Array is not defined". When I at that point say "var a = new Array();" I indeed get the error again. When I say "var a = [];", it works. But I need Date too..

Comment: The "initialize" error happens in Firefox too; the function really is not defined. Why is it referenced in the "onload"?

Comment: @Pointy I've no idea, the only part of the software I can control, is the iframe code.. the rest is CMS he bought from a company. Why would the not-existing of the initialize in the body crash IE9 but not 8 or other browsers?

Comment: What happens when you alert [].constructor?

Comment: Is the movie player inside a complete HTML page in the frame?

Comment: first off define a function initialize and see if the problem goes away, second, figure out how to remove it in the CMS or call up the people that wrote the thing!

Comment: That is all dependent on how and when they try to execute it and how bad they find the issue. You for sure need to remove the initialize or add it to one of the scripts as `function initialize() {;}`

Comment: initialize has been removed by the company, but the problem still remains.. the iframe code cannot find Array

Comment: @Pointy yes the movie player html page is complete, and if you view the page separately in its own tab, the page renders fine. It's the combination with the javascript popup that causes the crash somehow.

Comment: @Bergi [].constructor is "function Array() { [native code] }"

Comment: ...but window.Array got overwritten somewhere?!

Comment: @Bergi yes, new Array() does not work, [] does, at that point in debugging time. I can change objects to {} probably, but I cannot override Date with some shortcut. Besides, that would be annoying since Object is used in jquery and so on.. That's the magic bug :-)

Comment: One thing that may be of importance: I see `new Array` in a function that's overriding `getElementsByClassName`.  That may be the root of the problem. IE9 already has a built-in `getElementsByClassName`, I think.

Comment: @Pointy but why would that be a problem? I can override 'alert' or any other function too if I'd like that.. Isn't that a feature? Also, the page works fine if you view it without its iframe parent! That's the annoying part I don't understand :(

Comment: I don't know; when dealing with weird IE behavior it helps to treat such things as biological issues and not logical ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally solved by loading the iframe dynamically.

The solution was found on http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=73

Copy/paste here for future reference:

> I think this issue is more to do with how IE9 handles iframe and
>   subsequent loading of javascript in it... my workaround was to set
>   iframe src only 'onShow' callback function and somehow i stopped
>   getting those object undefined errors. Hope this helps.
>
> function onShow(){
>      jQuery("iframe").attr("src", "/goto/site");
>   }

Another link with possibly more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4

The solution implemented was loading the iframe src after the popup had fully rendered, instead of first loading the iframe and then showing the popup.

Thanks to all investigators!