# Multiple errors using iFrame on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

I have an `iframe` inside a `div` in my page like this:

```
<div id="ModalContato" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
    <iframe id="IfrModalContato" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="" style="width: 100%;
        height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

And in my page there is a button inside a grid that calls this function:

```
function AbreModalContato() {
    $("#IfrModalContato")[0].src = "ContatoModal.aspx?Modal=1&IdContatoPai=" + $("#ctl00_Corpo_HidIdContato").val();
    $("#ModalContato").dialog({ modal: true, title: 'Cadastro de contatos', width: 970, height: 570 });
    $("#ModalContato").dialog('open');
}
```

When I click on the button that opens the modal, I get a lot of JS errors like:

```
'Array' is not defined
'Object' is not defined
'Function' is not defined
```

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898487/javascript-array-object-date-not-defined) there's a guy that seems to have a problem just like mine(mine also happens only with IE9), but as a noob on JS and jQuery I don't know how to adapt my code to what he says.

I tried something like this:

```
function onShow() {
    $("#IfrModalContato").attr("src", "ContatoModal.aspx?Modal=1&IdContatoPai=" + $("#ctl00_Corpo_HidIdContato").val());
    $("#ModalContato").dialog({ modal: true, title: 'Cadastro de contatos', width: 970, height: 570 });
    $("#ModalContato").dialog('open');         
}
```

But that just won't work for me.
Anyone?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post on jsfiddle or something? So it will be easier for us to edit and test your code. thanks

Comment: Well, I'm working with asp.net and I just know that jsfiddle executes js code, but honestly, I don't know how to paste my code there in a way it will run. If I paste the code of all my page here will help you on something?

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle for your. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/FSTXP/) But I don't know why it says that the function is not defined. Im confused :/

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess but make sure your not including the same jquery script file in the frame and on the page. IE doesn't like this, which is why I stay clear of iFrames or just use one set of scripts in the parent page which you can use on the iFrame window.